# How do I prevent a `@typescript-eslint/unbound-method` error when using `useFormikContent()`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I have just updated some `@typescript-eslint` modules to the latest versions:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.4.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.4.0",
```

and am now getting the following error

```
  22:9  error  Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
```

for the code

```
const { setFieldTouched } = useFormikContext();
```

which is in the same form as in the [Formik docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useFormikContext)

How do I get around this error?

Comment: https://github.com/formik/formik/issues/2589

Answer (score 3):

Actually setFieldTouched does not use 'this' reference, so you can just disable error:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
const { setFieldTouched } = useFormikContext();
```

Second option is to call setFieldTouched like object method:

```
  const formikContext = useFormikContext();
  const setFieldTouched = (field: string, isTouched?: boolean, shouldValidate?: boolean) =>
formikContext.setFieldTouched(field, isTouched, shouldValidate);
```

Comment: How do you know `setFieldTouched` does not use `this` reference?